# Elasticsearch does not score all matched docs?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have 500k docs in the index.

The query I run is (with profile set to true):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "name" : "Foo Bar"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "sort": {
        "_score": "desc"
    },
    "profile": true
}
```

And the result is:

```
"score_count": 30771
```

Does it mean that ES computed score only for 30771 documents?
The matched docs count is +- 450 000.

Should it work like: compute score for all docs that match the query then sort them?

If the provided query is executed with `ASC` order of `_score` then the profile API returns `score_count` with +-450k which means score has been computed for every document.

PS.
Version 7.4

**EDITED**

Here is the response with flag `profile` set to `true`:

```
{
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
      {
        "id": "[Uav4XQTFQAwrUhIowzDmNw][foobar][0]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "BooleanQuery",
                "description": "name:foo name:bar",
                "time_in_nanos": 4189986,
                "breakdown": {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count": 10,
                  "match_count": 10550,
                  "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score": 2976,
                  "next_doc": 1877718,
                  "match": 397822,
                  "next_doc_count": 10550,
                  "score_count": 10546,
                  "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score": 0,
                  "advance": 33468,
                  "advance_count": 5,
                  "score": 1572858,
                  "build_scorer_count": 10,
                  "create_weight": 121295,
                  "shallow_advance": 0,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "build_scorer": 152177
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "TermQuery",
                    "description": "name:foo",
                    "time_in_nanos": 2027886,
                    "breakdown": {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                      "match_count": 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count": 105,
                      "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                      "next_doc": 0,
                      "match": 0,
                      "next_doc_count": 0,
                      "score_count": 10317,
                      "compute_max_score_count": 105,
                      "compute_max_score": 35785,
                      "advance": 938612,
                      "advance_count": 10343,
                      "score": 892043,
                      "build_scorer_count": 15,
                      "create_weight": 65054,
                      "shallow_advance": 19583,
                      "create_weight_count": 1,
                      "build_scorer": 55923
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TermQuery",
                    "description": "name:bar",
                    "time_in_nanos": 358254,
                    "breakdown": {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count": 10,
                      "match_count": 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count": 108,
                      "set_min_competitive_score": 934,
                      "next_doc": 0,
                      "match": 0,
                      "next_doc_count": 0,
                      "score_count": 1639,
                      "compute_max_score_count": 105,
                      "compute_max_score": 8923,
                      "advance": 154847,
                      "advance_count": 1647,
                      "score": 137159,
                      "build_scorer_count": 15,
                      "create_weight": 28964,
                      "shallow_advance": 10313,
                      "create_weight_count": 1,
                      "build_scorer": 13589
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 11096,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time_in_nanos": 3086399,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                    "reason": "search_top_hits",
                    "time_in_nanos": 2273851
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the response with flag `track_total_hits` set to `true`

```
{
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
      {
        "id": "[Uav4XQTFQAwrUhIowzDmNw][foobar][0]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "BooleanQuery",
                "description": "name:foo name:bar",
                "time_in_nanos": 139698953,
                "breakdown": {
                  "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                  "match_count": 0,
                  "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                  "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                  "next_doc": 63775687,
                  "match": 0,
                  "next_doc_count": 456130,
                  "score_count": 456130,
                  "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                  "compute_max_score": 0,
                  "advance": 1527064,
                  "advance_count": 5,
                  "score": 70029529,
                  "build_scorer_count": 10,
                  "create_weight": 3148307,
                  "shallow_advance": 0,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "build_scorer": 306090
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "TermQuery",
                    "description": "name:foo",
                    "time_in_nanos": 71838139,
                    "breakdown": {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                      "match_count": 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                      "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                      "next_doc": 26692491,
                      "match": 0,
                      "next_doc_count": 455898,
                      "score_count": 455898,
                      "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                      "compute_max_score": 0,
                      "advance": 9269,
                      "advance_count": 5,
                      "score": 44081855,
                      "build_scorer_count": 15,
                      "create_weight": 46023,
                      "shallow_advance": 0,
                      "create_weight_count": 1,
                      "build_scorer": 96684
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "TermQuery",
                    "description": "name:bar",
                    "time_in_nanos": 4989481,
                    "breakdown": {
                      "set_min_competitive_score_count": 0,
                      "match_count": 0,
                      "shallow_advance_count": 0,
                      "set_min_competitive_score": 0,
                      "next_doc": 133219,
                      "match": 0,
                      "next_doc_count": 2409,
                      "score_count": 2409,
                      "compute_max_score_count": 0,
                      "compute_max_score": 0,
                      "advance": 1512687,
                      "advance_count": 5,
                      "score": 247728,
                      "build_scorer_count": 15,
                      "create_weight": 3075122,
                      "shallow_advance": 0,
                      "create_weight_count": 1,
                      "build_scorer": 15886
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 8333,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time_in_nanos": 122650720,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                    "reason": "search_top_hits",
                    "time_in_nanos": 85187889
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the total hit? I think it should be 30771

Comment: `"track_total_hits": true` returns 500k. What is more, with that parameter, the `Profile API` returns for `score_count` not 30771 but 500k. Does it mean that ES has some optimizations that in some unknown way it does not compute the score for all docs ?

Comment: can you share profile API full response?

Comment: Sure, I pasted it in main question.

Comment: @szufi1 `The Profile API gives the user insight into how search requests are executed at a low level so that the user can understand why certain requests are slow, and take steps to improve them. ` - `low level` - that's why it may not be considered all docs.